# Starting many unrelated jobs in parallel on Grid Engine?

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub, sungridengine

I often want to start a set of entirely unrelated ("embarrassingly" parallel) jobs on a Grid Engine cluster, for load-balancing purposes.

What I do at the moment, I generate one Bash script for each job and then submit each of them separately, all controlled by a Perl-script that I wrote.

If I just put all jobs into one file, one line one job, then Grid Engine will execute the jobs sequentially which is besides the point.

Is there any way how I can have just one file, and tell Grid Engine that it should execute each line/job in parallel?

Basically I want something like Grid Engine Array Jobs. But the problem with array jobs is, they only work if the changing element between each job is a number, or an index in an array, and also if this number/index is evenly spaced. But I am talking about jobs that are completely unrelated and do not share a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You submit an array job using a moderately powerful interpreter to convert the $SGE_TASK_ID into whatever you want:

```
#$ -t 1-3    
#$ -S /bin/bash
case $SGE_TASK_ID in
1)echo "I'm a teapot short and stout";;
2)cat /etc/passwd;;
3)touch ~/job3run;;
esac
```